# Need assistance with T-SQL cursor, Essentially retrieving an integer that is +1 the previous row

Tags: t-sql, database-cursor

I'm attempting to create a fixed position file and am running into a snag. Essentially, I need to create an ID that is based off on an auto number.

I have a variable that tells me the last number used. So for example:

```
DECLARE @lastNumUsed int = 1
```

After doing some research online, I think I can accomplish this with a cursor. I'm unfamiliar with cursors so bear with me.

My end goal is this:
If I have 3 payeeIDs EX:
101
110
165

I need to find the last vid I used (1) and assign 101 to 2, 110 to 3, 165 to 4.

Right now I get:

2
3
3

NOTE that the vid is nvarchar because getting this number is only the first step in creating what I need. it will eventually be an alphanumeric field.

Can somebody point me to the right direction?

```
DECLARE @payeeID int;
DECLARE @vid as nvarchar(12);
DECLARE @VIDCursor as CURSOR;

SET @VIDCursor = CURSOR FOR
select 
    distinct @payeeID
    ,@VIDCursor
 from #tmpTable;

Open @VIDCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @VIDCursor INTO @payeeID, @vid;

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN

    Print @vid 

    FETCH NEXT FROM @VIDCursor INTO @payeeID, @vid 

    Set @vid  = @vid  + 1

END

Close @VIDCursor;
Deallocate @VIDCursor;
```

Update: I believe the responses below are way better but if anyone finds it helpful, I did get the cursor to work, but I'll be updating my code to not use a cursor and use the row_number() instead.

```
DECLARE @payeeID int;
DECLARE @vid int

Create TABLE #tmpTable
(
    payeeID int,
    vid int
)

DECLARE @VIDCursor as CURSOR;
SET @VIDCursor = CURSOR FOR 
select 
    distinct payeeID 
from #tmpItemizedDetails;

Open @VIDCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @VIDCursor INTO @payeeID;

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    Set @vid = @vid + 1

    Insert into #tmpVoucherNumbers values (@payeeID,@vid );

    FETCH NEXT FROM @VIDCursor INTO @payeeID 

END

Close @VIDCursor ;
Deallocate @VIDCursor ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this without cursors, for example:

```
DECLARE @lastNumUsed INT = 1
SELECT  payeeID, ISNULL(@lastNumUsed,0)+ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY payeeID) AS vid
FROM    #tmpTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correctly what you want is a row numbering in the order of payeeID , starting with the last used +1?

How about:

```
Declare @LastVidUsed int=1
SELECT payeeID
       , row_number() over (order by payeeID) + @LastVidUsed vid
FROM #TMP
GROUP BY payeeID
```

The cursor solution you have started is, I am sorry to say, a mess, I wouldn't got that way anyhow!

Comment: Nice! I like the approach. I'm not familiar with cursors, but was the best I response I was getting over the web! Thanks.